# COM+ Application Set UP new service

Tags: powershell, com

I have a  COM plus Application Of activation type 1, i.e server Type Application.
    And its identity is Network Service.Now I need to set Up following properties for this application.

```
Activation->RUN as NT service->Setup New Service->Select Dependencies
```

How can i do this programmatically through Powershell? I searched lot on web but could not find any property through which i can set these up.

Comment: have you looked at the COM+ Administration Catalog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687653(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: @Matt Yes i have seen this but it does not contain the property which i require to set.What i can over Net is only high level properties,like activation.But Under activation Tab,if i need to set Some things,i am not getting that.